# Moq & Unit Test AspBoilerPlate .Net Core 3 throw exception "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly"

Tags: unit-testing, moq, xunit, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to test file upload service by pathing `IFormFile` object but it throws exception when pathing moqed file to target service.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ReadSheetFile_Test()
{
    var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    fileMock.Setup(x => x.FileName).Returns("file1.xlsx");
    var result = _voucherAppService.ReadSheetFile(fileMock.Object);    
    result.Count().ShouldBe(0);
}
```

Exception

> Property accessor 'Location' on object System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder threw the following exception:'The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading plug-in DLL files, "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091221/loading-plug-in-dll-files-the-invoked-member-is-not-supported-in-a-dynamic-ass)

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `ReadSheetFile` method?